# Can Book schema be used to a web page containing only a single page of a book

Tags: schema.org

If we have web pages, each [AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/) web page contains a single page of a book, can the [Book schema](https://schema.org/Book) be used in each one of them? or it must be used only in a full book?